# Is there any limit in python's requirements.txt during the installation?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any limit in python's requirements.txt during the installation?

I've tried to search for this answer publicly but I can't find whether is it possible to install a big number of packages at once from the requirements.txt.

To give you more context on this weird condition, I started working at CTFQ21EmpireTmp and I found that they are storing their python packages in their private repository. I'm working on a project that analyze all these packages so I've managed to retrieve all the packages names in the requirements.txt (literally billions of private packages). Well retrieving the packages names was not really difficult since all the packages names follows the `ctf-q21-empire-tmp-[a-z0-9\-]{5,10}` regular expression (all the regex combinations are almost existing).

I was asking about whether there is any limit because the number of packages is huge and I don't want the analysis to abort especially that the analysis is going to be quick (we're using a scaling infrastructure  which means that the installation of all these packages should be done in less than 5 minutes. The issue is since the installation run every 5 minutes to make sure that the stored private packages are analyzed as soon as possible, we are disabling the installation output. That's why I don't believe that there is a way to check if there was an issue with the requirements.txt length or number of lines.

I don't know whether what is passed from the first part of the following command to the second part can be broken (too much for the pipe `|`). Basically, we're using this command:
`cat requirement.txt | pip3 install -I`
And with the following configuration of `/etc/pip.conf`

```
[global]
extra-index-url = http://<private_IP_and_port>/simple/
trusted-host = <private_IP>
```

With this, the packages are installed from the private repository.

We avoided installing the packages using the `-r requirements.txt` parameter to avoid any issue coming from pip3.

For anyone that is curious what if a project was decommissioned, well before the billions of packages start their installation, the old installed packages are removed (initially there is no installed pip package not even from the public repository).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I come back to give my feedback about this issue. We didn't noticed any error when we used the pipe | to pass what comes from the requirements.txt to the pip3 command. So I can close this issue as solved since there was no limit in the file's length

Comment: I'll mark this as a solution in 2 days (the system will not allow me to mark it now)